# Issue with shebang python - import command not found

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am tring to run a simple mapper code in python, unix is not recognizing my shebang line, i searched in lot of forums and everywhere it is suggested to add sehbang line and give permission to that file. I did both, but still its not working. It is working only when i add python before the file.

```
hduser@master:~/code$ ls
mapper.py  reducer.py
hduser@master:~/code$ ls -l
total 8
-rwxrwxr-x 1 hduser hduser 225 Sep 16 07:57 mapper.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hduser hduser 663 Sep 16 07:56 reducer.py
hduser@master:~/code$ echo "foo foo quux labs foo bar quux" | python /home/hduser/code/mapper.py
foo     1
foo     1
quux    1
labs    1
foo     1
bar     1
quux    1
hduser@master:~/code$ which python
/usr/bin/python
hduser@master:~/code$ echo "foo foo quux labs foo bar quux" | /home/hduser/code/mapper.py
/home/hduser/code/mapper.py: line 5:
Created on 16/09/2014

@author: jee
: No such file or directory
/home/hduser/code/mapper.py: line 7: $'\r': command not found
/home/hduser/code/mapper.py: line 8: import: command not found
/home/hduser/code/mapper.py: line 9: $'\r': command not found
/home/hduser/code/mapper.py: line 11: syntax error near unexpected token `line'
'home/hduser/code/mapper.py: line 11: `    line = line.strip()
hduser@master:~/code$ vim mapper.py
'''
Created on 16/09/2014

@author: jee
'''
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    words = line.split()
    for word in words:
        print('%s\t%s' % (word, 1))
```

Comment: Yes i did. You can see that -rwxrwxr-x 1 hduser hduser 225 Sep 16 07:57 mapper.py

Comment: I tried to run using this -- echo "foo foo quux labs foo bar quux" | /home/hduser/code/mapper.py

Comment: you need echo `"foo foo quux labs foo bar quux" | ./mapper.py`, you have to use `./` to run it. Or with full path `foo foo quux labs foo bar quux" | /home/hduser/code/./mapper.py`

Comment: Tried, no luck.. :( Even i tried to run after keeping it as a present working directory.. :( hduser@master:~/code$ echo "foo foo quux labs foo bar quux" | ./map.py
-bash: ./map.py: /usr/bin/python^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Comment: did you edit the file on windows?

Comment: Yup.. My machine is a windows one and the cluster where i am trying to run this is a ubuntu one.. OMG, how many things we should keep in mind..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shebang has to go into the first line of your code.

As it currently stands, you are creating a python statement(the triple quotes), and then importing the shebang.

So, the correct version will be

```
#!/usr/bin/python
'''
Created on 16/09/2014

@author: jee
'''

import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    words = line.split()
    for word in words:
        print('%s\t%s' % (word, 1))
```

***Edit***

You have a extra character in your shebang line, the windows File ending character. Remove it and you should be good to go. You can check [this link](http://techtips-it.blogspot.in/2011/04/can-i-convert-file-format-in-notepad.html) to see how to change the encoding in notepadd++.

Comment: No luck.. :( It is throwing me an error .. Also, it seems to be an additional character present over there..  hduser@master:~/code$ echo "foo foo quux labs foo bar quux" | /home/hduser/code/mapper.py
-bash: /home/hduser/code/mapper.py: /usr/bin/python^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
hduser@master:~/code$ ls
mapper.py  reducer.py

Comment: Guys, its not working. Even if i copy paste this or type by my own. Also i pasted my code in to notepad and seen if there is any extracharacter. Nothing as such.. But i dont know how come i am getting bad interpreter error.. :(-bash: /home/hduser/code/map.py: /usr/bin/python^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Comment: @Jeeva You have a extra character in your shebang line, the windows File ending character. Remove it and you should be good to go... You can check [this link](http://techtips-it.blogspot.in/2011/04/can-i-convert-file-format-in-notepad.html) to see how to change the encoding in notepadd++

Comment: My answer was being typed at the same time as @mu. When I start entering my answer there was no answer. I feel bad now ...

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 There is nothing to feel bad about, just enjoy the rep :)

Comment: Awesome.. That worked.. :) Thanks a lot.. Now I marked yours as the solution ... Cheers.. :)

Comment: Thanks to you too @TonySuffolk66

Comment: So this is not really a problem with the shbang. Whenever we move a python script from windows to unix or reverse, make sure to change the file format. Otherwise, not only will the script not work, sometimes doing a 'which' on the file also does not work!

Answer (score 5):

The #! has to be on the first line:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
'''
Created on 16/09/2014

@author: jee
'''

import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
     line = line.strip()
     words = line.split()
     for word in words:
         print('%s\t%s' % (word, 1))
```

Comment: hduser@master:~/code$ echo "foo foo quux labs foo bar quux" | /home/hduser/code/mapper.py
-bash: /home/hduser/code/mapper.py: /usr/bin/python^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
hduser@master:~/code$ ls
mapper.py  reducer.py
hduser@master:~/code$ echo "foo foo quux labs foo bar quux" | /home/hduser/code/mapper.py
-bash: /home/hduser/code/mapper.py: /usr/bin/python^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
hduser@master:~/code$ echo "foo foo quux labs foo bar quux" | python /home/hduser/code/mapper.py
foo     1
foo     1
quux    1
labs    1
foo     1
bar     1
quux    1

Comment: As others have said - check for unusual characters.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Dan :-) sloppy language on my part.